# How to initialize the value from trait in subtype?

Tags: scala, traits

If I write :

```
trait T {
  val t = 3
  val u = 1::t::Nil
}

class U extends T {
  override val t = 2
}

(new U).u
```

it shows this.

```
List(1, 0)
```

How should I change the above code to make it display the following:

```
List(1, 2)
```

i.e. `override val t` sets the value of `t` for `u` in the trait `T`?

Comment: you could define u as `lazy val`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do this is to delay evaluation of `u` by using `def` or `lazy val` as follows:

```
trait T {
  def t = 3
  def u = 1::t::Nil
}

class U extends T {
  override def t = 2
}

(new U).u
```

or

```
trait T {
  val t = 3
  lazy val u = 1::t::Nil
}

class U extends T {
  override val t = 2
}

(new U).u
```

The differences are as follows:

- `val` makes an expression evaluate during initialization
- `def` makes an expression evaluate each time `u` is used
- `lazy val` makes it evaluated on first `u` usage and caches the result

Answer (score 10):

Try using an early initializer:

```
scala> trait T {
     |   val t = 3
     |   val u = 1::t::Nil
     | }
defined trait T

scala> class U extends {
     | override val t = 2;
     | } with T
defined class U

scala> (new U).u
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer) for more information about early initialization.

Comment: Although correct, for readability reasons, I prefer to use the cache method with lazy vals.
If I need to add code to my class U, I cannot put it in the brackets, I need to create another group, like class U extends { override val t=2} with T { ... my code here ...}

Comment: The issue with this approach is that every access is synchronized to make sure that the `lazy val` is in fact ready. It slows down application and should not be used blindly on critical paths.

Answer (score 4):

All scala declarative style is just an illusion. Scala is build upon a jvm and works like java.

Evetything is a class and should be independent on its usage (java is not c++ and supports incremental build with its pros and cons). Every trait has its own initialization code and multi-trait class runs respective initialization code one by one. If you use some AnyRef that is declared only in a subclass than that its value will be set for null during initialization.

I guard myself with specifing convention rule: every val should be either final or lazy ([why using plain val in non-final classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091689/why-using-plain-val-in-non-final-classes)) . So I don't care about initialization order and may pretend further that I'm using declarative language.

Also I'm using option `-Xcheckinit`: Add runtime check to field accessors.